# Open Tag - Close Tag " { } " - How can to formating

Tags: database, excel, pivot

Hello on excel i have big data.Is only one column the data and i want split by tags "{" and "}". On column the image is like that: 
`{{[math1];1;1;5.6617};{[math2];1;1;34.3131};{[math3];1;1;4.5293}}`

If i format the text is like that:

```
{
    {[math1];1;1;5.6617}; //Math1
    {[math2];1;1;34.3131}; //Math2
    {[math3];1;1;4.5293} //Math3
}
```

i want split //Math1 , //Math2 & //Math3

The data is from SQL server maybe help this. I can use any tool extra on excel for data model?

Comment: Select your column. Goto `Data` tab. `Text To Columns` -> `Delimited(Next)` -> Check `Other` -> fill `/` in the text field -> `Finish`

Comment: My bad sorry i need split that 
{[math1];1;1;5.6617}; -column 1
{[math2];1;1;34.3131}; - column 2
{[math3];1;1;4.5293}  - colimn 3 
I want focus on "{" why have a motive ..

Answer (score 1):

Following should be helpful though not sure its the best way to solve your problem.

For first part i.e. Math1, use the following formula

```
=MID(A1,2,SEARCH("};",A1,1)-1)
```

For second part i.e. Math2, use the following formula

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("};",A1,1)+2,SEARCH("};",A1,SEARCH("};",A1,1)+1)-SEARCH("};",A1,1)-1)
```

For third part i.e. Math3, use

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("};",A1,SEARCH("};",A1,1)+1)+2,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("};",A1,SEARCH("};",A1,1)+1)-2)
```

See image for reference

[image]